# Realm losing data for no apparent reason

Tags: android, realm

i'm having a problem with data loss in realm.

Basically, i save some data in realm from a class, then i call an API and in the response i need the data i saved to use for parsing.

The problem is that when i retrieve the data saved in realm (actually saved, i checked in debug) it returns nothing, so something is deleting it.

Weird thing is this appens only the first time i save this data, when none of this models are saved, also i have no method to delete this data

this is where i save the data and call the API, at the end of an AsynkTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mContacts);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        mContacts = DaoContacts.getAllContactsSortedAsList();
        mDataChangeCallback.onDataSetChanged();
        PojoRequestCheckNumbers numbers = new PojoRequestCheckNumbers();
        for (int i = 0; i < mContacts.size(); i++) {
            for (ModelNumber n : mContacts.get(i).getNumbers()) {
                numbers.addNumber(n.getNumber());
            }
        }
        if (numbers.size() > 0)
            ApiManager.checkNumbers(new RequestCheckContacts(this, numbers));
        mLoadCallback.onPostContactsLoad();
    }
```

This is where i load the data from realm, it's inside the response of the API call (in this i also generate a hash map for other reasons, but the hashmap is empty too, because it's generated from the contacts.

```
JSONArray jsonNumbers = responseJson.getJSONArray(NUMBERS_FIELD);
ArrayList<ModelContact> contacts = DaoContacts.getAllContactsSortedAsList();
Map numberMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
for (ModelContact m : contacts) {
   for (ModelNumber s : m.getNumbers()) {
       numberMap.put(s.getNumber(), m.get_ID());
   }
}
```

Just after this i get an error when i try to retrieve data from the hashmap because it's obviously empty.

```
try {
   //TODO: check why null
   long contact_id = (long) numberMap.get(jsonNumbers.getString(i)); <-- ERROR
   for (ModelContact mc : contacts) {
       if (mc.get_ID() == contact_id) {
           for (ModelNumber n : mc.getNumbers()) {
               if (jsonNumbers.getString(i).equals(n.getNumber())) {
                   realm.beginTransaction();
                   n.setHasApp(true);
                   realm.commitTransaction();
               }
           }
        }
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT 1:

This is the Dao function i use:

```
public static ArrayList<ModelContact> getAllContactsSortedAsList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(getAllContactsSorted());
}

public static RealmResults<ModelContact> getAllContactsSorted(){
    return Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ModelContact.class).findAllSorted(ModelContact.NAME_NORMALIZED, Sort.ASCENDING);
}
```

EDIT 2:

This whole thing happens when i open the app for the first time, when the app has never saved this Model data in Realm ( keep in mind that when i get the error, the Realm for my ModelContact should contain data because i already saved all my data before calling the API ), and keeps happening until i restart the app.
Once i restart the app, (now having data already in the realm for my ModelContact) everything works fine.

Comment: Please explain why you are using these Maps and JSONArrays when you could be using `RealmResults` and GSON automatic json mapping to pojo classes?

Comment: It's because i have a list of data returned from the API and i would need to iterate through that saved data once for each item returned by the API and in that iteration i'd need to iterate nested data, with that map i cut some iterations

Comment: So the problem is `getAllContactsSortedAsList()` returns empty results? Could you please share the code of `getAllContactsSortedAsList()`?

Comment: i've added the code, any clues on why this is happening?

Comment: I doubt when the `getAllContactsSortedAsList` called, the Realm instance on that caller thread has not been refreshed yet. Take a look at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications and please consider to more the `getAllContactsSortedAsList` into a `RealmChangeListerner` callback.

Comment: I will definitely try that, but it should be updated because te query is synchronous

Comment: It actually worked, i've made an onChange listener in the request response, but there no change was made so i had to cause one adding an empty object to realm, and in the onChange somehow the data was present